# Concatenate or Combine Multiple Values and Retain Fonts and Colour

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate or combine a few cells together and keep their individual styles.

For instance:

```
A1: Mr (Arial, Red, size 10)
A2: Joseph (Courier, Blue, size 20)
A3: Lion (Arial, Green, size 15)
```

Using the function `=A1&" "&A2&" "&A3`

```
A5: Mr Joseph Lion (Default font, default colour, default Size)
```

In the Concatenated cell A5, all the fonts, sizes and colours go back to default.

Is there a way to combine the values and maintain the styles.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function (`RICHTEXTCONCAT()`) to concatenate rich text from your Sheets:

```js
function isCell(obj) {
  return (typeof obj == "object" && obj.toString() == "Range" && obj.getHeight() == 1 && obj.getWidth() == 1);
}

function RICHTEXTCONCAT() {
  var nargs = arguments.length;
  var resultText = "";
  var styles = [];

  for (var i=0; i<nargs; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    if (isCell(arg)) {
      var startPos = resultText.length;
      resultText += arg.getValue();
      var rtv = arg.getRichTextValue();
      if (rtv) {
        var runs = rtv.getRuns();
        for (var j=0; j<runs.length; j++) {
          styles.push({startIndex: startPos + runs[j].getStartIndex(),
                       endIndex:   startPos + runs[j].getEndIndex(),
                       textStyle: runs[j].getTextStyle().copy().build()});
        }
      }
    } else if (typeof arg == "string") {
      resultText += arg;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Unsupported type " + typeof arg + " for argument " + (i+1) + ". Must be a cell or a string.");
    }
  }

  var result = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(resultText);
  for (var i=0; i<styles.length; i++) {
    if (styles[i].startIndex === styles[i].endIndex) continue;
    result.setTextStyle(styles[i].startIndex,
                        styles[i].endIndex,
                        styles[i].textStyle);
  }
  return result.build();
}
```

In theory, you could use the function as a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), so that it could be used in a cell such as:

```
=RICHTEXTCONCAT(A1, " ", A2, " ", A3)
```

However, Sheets does **not** interpret rich text [return values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values) from custom functions. That means that the only option you have is to manually call a Google Apps Script function that uses [`setRichTextValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue) in order to execute it. An example:

```js
function myConcat() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range1 = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var range2 = sheet.getRange("A2");
  var range3 = sheet.getRange("A3");
  var result = RICHTEXTCONCAT(range1, " ", range2, " ", range3);

  var destinationRange = sheet.getRange("A5");
  destinationRange.setRichTextValue(result);
}
```

If you are interested in Rich Text Value being a possible return value from a custom function, please consider filing a Feature Request into Google's Public Issue Tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Thank you for this, 

How would I amend it to only show the ones that contain data? for instance, if only two of the cells contain values - ignore the other

Comment: Hello @JosephLion, glad you liked my answer. I have made a small modification - so that should work now. Let me know if that does the trick for you. Cheers

Comment: How can I achieve the same rich concatenation in Excel?

Comment: @JosephLion Hey Joseph, I am sorry to say - I work exclusively using Google Apps Script and Sheets, and I have never programmed macros for excel. However, I have found [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4622-excel-concatenate-keep-text-color.html) resource online which may be of your interest. In case it doesn't fix/help you fix your issue, I suggest you create a brand new question.

Comment: thanks @carlesgg97 I appreciate that, thank you for your continued help